# Hive Php program not getting htrift library path

Tags: php, hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop/hive. I have succesfully installed hadoop and hive. I am trying to use hive php program mentioned here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient to retrieve employee results. Bu some how my program is not getting the path of Thrift PHP Class. Can anyone help?

Hive installation path
/usr/local/lib/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin

PHP program path
/usr/local/lib/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/scripts

PHP Thrift Library Path
/usr/local/lib/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/php

My Current Working Directory
/usr/local/lib/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/scripts

Below is how my program looks

```
<?php
    // set THRIFT_ROOT to php directory of the hive distribution
    $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = '../lib/php/';    
    // load the required files for connecting to Hive
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'packages/hive_service    /ThriftHive.php';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'transport/TSocket.php';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';
    // Set up the transport/protocol/client
    $transport = new TSocket('localhost', 10000);
    $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
    $client = new ThriftHiveClient($protocol);
    $transport->open();

    // run queries, metadata calls etc
    $client->execute('SELECT * from employee');
    var_dump($client->fetchAll());
    $transport->close();
?>
```

Comment: Could it be that big space? On line 5.
`require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'packages/hive_service    /ThriftHive.php';`

Comment: no its not related with that. space is just posted by mistake

Comment: Hive client library for php is not well formed it is comprises of lots of errors. Please suggest if any other library exists for php.

Comment: After a quick google search: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Automattic/php-thrift-sql) will do? Sorry, I haven't actually worked with hive/hadoop before.